# Convert integer value of hours into formatted hours in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I'm trying to convert my integer value of hours, 0-23 into a nicely formatted one like:

```
15 would be represented like: 15:00
0 would be represetnted like: 00:00
23 like: 23:00
```

This is the code from my view:

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.HourlyGraph)
 {
   @:{device: '@item.Hour', geekbench:@item.Sales },
 }
```

I'm trying to represent the @item.Hour value like I mentioned above. I've  tried using interpolated string like this:

```
"{@item.Hour}:00"
```

But in my view says it's not supported since I use C# 5.0 instead of C# 6.0 ...

How could do this instead of using interpolated strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use standard string formatting for integers which will prepend a zero if necessary:

```
@item.Hour.ToString("D2")
```

Comment: for 0 I get 00, it's missing the :00 part XD

Comment: Well, what's preventing you from adding it? I mean isn't `@item.Hour.ToString("D2"):00` working for you? It looks like pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use the `ToString` method?

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.HourlyGraph)
 {
   @:{device: '@item.Hour.ToString("00")<text>:00</text>', geekbench:@item.Sales },
 }
```

Comment: Matt, this gives ,me for 23 like following: 00:23

Comment: Instead it shuold be 23:00

Comment: Of course. My mistake. Check my updated answer. And am I correct in understanding that you will never show any minutes? Will the minutes always be "00"?